# Failed to convert parameter value from a TimeSpan to a DateTime

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, datetime

I am using SQL Server 2008.

First I gave `SqlDbType.Time` for `System.TimeSpan` to the parameter type for Insert and Update.

I works successfully.

Now I changed to `DbType.Time` instead of `SqlDbType.Time`. Which gave me the error message "Failed to convert parameter value from a TimeSpan to a DateTime" which didn't call the "Procedure"

Answer (score 5):

This is a [confirmed bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=381934) in the current version of ADO.Net. Until, the next release, you need to use SqlDbType.Time.

Comment: is it still a bug or it is fixed @jose basilio as i am currently facing the same problem with c# 4.0 any help will be appreciated

Comment: They still haven't fixed this bug -- they closed the ticket with the workaround mentioned in this answer (which is not an option if you need to work with an `IDataParameter`).