# Exception :Failed to convert parameter value from a TimeSpan to a DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, timespan

When tried to pass timespan value c# to a stored procedure containing parameter value as time(7) datatype, I am getting an error.

In c#:

```
 Db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@in_Duration", DbType.Time, aV.Duration);
```

I have specified time as the parameter.

In Stored Procedure the @in_duration is of datatype **time(7)**.
In table also, the column datatype is **time(7)**.
Let me know what is the actual problem is

Comment: what is the type of `aV.Duration`??

Comment: What about changing to datetime2(7) in db? That should help

Comment: av.Duration is of datatype Timespan

Comment: When I need to store a media duration then there is no point in using datetime2 datatype. Need to use only time

Comment: Possible duplicates of [Failed to convert parameter value from a TimeSpan to a DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858200/failed-to-convert-parameter-value-from-a-timespan-to-a-datetime) and [Failed to convert parameter value from a TimeSpan to a DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771465/failed-to-convert-parameter-value-from-a-timespan-to-a-datetime).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SqlDbType.Time`. `DbType.Time` is a type representing a SQL Server DateTime value.

Comment: I am using AddinParameter function which accepts only DBType.Time as a parameter